# Devise API authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, api, devise

I am working on a rails web application that also provides JSON based API for mobile devices . mobile clients are expected to first obtain a token with (email/pass), then clients will make subsequential API calls with the token.

I am pretty new to Devise, and I am looking for a Devise API look like `authenticate(email, pass)` and expect it to return true/false, then based on that I will either create and hand back the token or return a decline message. but seems Devise doesn't provide something like this.

I am aware that Devise 1.3 provides JSON based auth, but that's a bit different from what I need - I need to generate token and handle back to client, then after that auth is done using the token instead.

Can someone please give some pointers?

Comment: This is a great question, unfortunately the answers are outdated. We need new answers for Rails 4. I'm hoping to get it working soon :)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

There is a devise configuration called `:token_authenticatable`. So if you add that to the devise method in your "user", then you can authenticate in your API just by calling

```
"/api/v1/recipes?qs=sweet&auth_token=[@user.auth_token]"
```

You'll probably want this in your user as well:

```
before_save :ensure_authentication_token
```

**UPDATE** (with API authorization code)

The method you're looking for are:

```
resource = User.find_for_database_authentication(:login=>params[:user_login][:login])
resource.valid_password?(params[:user_login][:password])
```

here's my [gist with a full scale JSON/API login with devise](https://gist.github.com/1255275)

Comment: thank you Jesse, my problem isn't actually about the token itself, it's about how to do a custom email/pass auth in JSON from mobile device, to obtain the token.

Comment: Updated with the method and gist you're looking for.

Comment: I get valid_password? undefined method error. I assume that valid_password is a method in Devise and i need not implement it

Comment: @AbhayKumar depends on the devise options. you might need database_authenticable --- please open a new question.

Comment: An update to people looking at this, `:token_authenticatable` is now deprecated.

Comment: If you get here after November 2013, you need to know that Authenticable has been removed from Devise, so this solution won't probably work. Check this out: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Simple-Token-Authentication-Example

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend reading through the [Devise Wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/_pages), as Devise natively supports token authentication as one of it's modules. I have not personally worked with token authentication in Devise, but Brandon Martin has an example token authentication example [here](http://zyphdesignco.com/blog/simple-auth-token-example-with-devise).

Comment: thanks, however my problem is how to auth with email/pass to obtain the token, and that needs to happen using JSON, I cannot have users type a token on mobile devices.

Comment: example link is broken

Answer (score 1):

Devise is based on Warden, an authentification middleware for Rack.

If you need to implement your own (alternative) way to authenticate a user, you should have a look at Warden in combination with the strategies that ship with Devise: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/tree/master/lib/devise/strategies

Answer (score 1):

If token auth just isn't what you want to do, you can also return a cookie and have the client include the cookie in the request header.  It works very similar to the web sessions controller.

In an API sessions controller

```
class Api::V1::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  def create
    warden.authenticate!(:scope => :user)
    render :json => current_user
  end

end
```

In Routes

```
namespace :api, :defaults => { :format => 'json' } do
  namespace :v1 do
    resource :account, :only => :show
    devise_scope :user do
      post :sessions, :to => 'sessions#create'
      delete :session, :to => 'sessions#destroy'
    end
  end
end
```

Then you can do this sort of thing (examples are using [HTTPie](https://github.com/jakubroztocil/httpie))

```
http -f POST localhost:3000/api/v1/sessions user[email]=user@email.com user[password]=passw0rd
```

The response headers will have a session in the Set-Cookie header.  Put the value of this in subsequent requests.

```
http localhost:3000/api/v1/restricted_things/1 'Cookie:_my_site_session=<sessionstring>; path=/; HttpOnly'
```