# Devise RegistrationsController create action in API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise

I'm trying to create a Rails 3 app with an API. I use Devise as my authentication system. I would like to make it possible to sign up and later sign in through the API. And i'm not quite sure how I should do this. I have created separated controllers to manage the API, i.e. `api/v1/account/1/projects.json`. I'm currently trying to create a custom `Devise::RegistrationsController` for the API, but I'm not quite sure how to do this.

My create action currently looks like this:

```
class API::V1::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  redpond_to :json, :xml

  def create
    build_resource
    if resource.save
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        # Account is a nested resource for User, I want to 
        # create an associated account when the User signs up through the client, 
        # how should I do this?
        account = resource.accounts.build 
        # How can I get the sign_in to work?
        sign_in(resource_name, resource)
        # Probably wrong
        respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      else
        # probably wrong
        expire_session_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, :location => after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      # probably wrong, or?
      clean_up_passwords resource
    end
  end
```

Which probably is very incorrect as mentioned in my comments, so I wonder if anyone could give me any guidance on how to make it work. Should also mention that account is a nested resource for the user.

I also wonder how I should set up the login and logout functionality in the API with Devise.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7614798/devise-api-authentication) other SO question may help you. It looks very similar. Pay special attention to the [gist](https://gist.github.com/1255275) that's linked in the answer.

Comment: I got the signing part working by following the links, with some modifications. The signup part will therefore probably also work. Thanks!