# Rails API--Do I need to store my Oauth2 access token?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm releasing an API for my Rails app, and securing it using Oauth2. I've setup Doorkeeper to handle the Oauth2 provider, and it works great. I can authenticate and setup a client--for a single session, following the tutorial [here](https://github.com/applicake/doorkeeper/wiki/Testing-your-provider-with-OAuth2-gem). I'd like to release a Gem for folks to access their account via the API, but I only want them to have to authenticate the app once. So, I have a few questions:

1. Do I need to store the access token to accomplish this? Most APIs require you to store a key and secret, but not also a token.
2. If I do need to store it, how do I instantiate a new token from that stored value?
3. If I need to store it, is it a problem, security-wise, to have a non-expiring token? If so, should I enable refresh tokens?

Generally speaking, is there a better/more standard approach to APIs? Users will be able to create shippable orders (i.e. there's money involved), so security is a pretty hefty concern here.

Answer (score 2):

I hope I got your question right. Please let me know if this is not the case. So here goes. OAuth2 has **resource owners** and **clients**. In your case, the users of the API are clients . Typically, they are providing service to the resource owners which involves accessing their resources on your system. Each client should get a client key and secret which are unique to her. They get it through the /oauth/applications UI that doorkeeper adds to your application. They need to provide this token and not your library. Anyway it could not do it since the key and secret are unique per client. You can read [here](http://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-28.html) to get a good understanding of the flow.

It might be the case that you don't really need OAuth2, since you don't have a concept of separate resource owners and client in your system. In such case, you don't have to use OAuth2. You can use simple token authentication (I think devise has such an option, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7614798/devise-api-authentication) for more details). You can also decide to use the client credentials flow in OAuth2, but it seems to me like an overkill.

Comment: You've understood correctly. Client = resource owner. My larger concern was security. My understanding is that simple token-based auth isn't all that secure, and folks seem to swear by Oauth. In other apps, which require less security, I've used Devise's token auth with great success.